# fixed right menu with 100% width content

Tags: html, css

when this menu is on the left the 100% width content is fine, as soon as i swap the menu from the left to right right the content is now 100% the whole width and not the space between the menu (its when i add right: 0; to the left menu to make it appear on right

jfiddle left menu: http://jsfiddle.net/mxadam/ZQQ6s/21/

jfiddle right menu: http://jsfiddle.net/mxadam/ZQQ6s/22/

left menu

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
font-size: 20px;
}

#left {
width: 300px;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
outline: 1px solid;
background: red;
z-index: 10;
}

#right {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
outline: 1px solid;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
background: blue;
left: 300px;
border-left: 10px solid #fff;
}
```

right menu

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
font-size: 20px;
}

#left {
width: 300px;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
outline: 1px solid;
background: red;
z-index: 10;
right: 0;
}

#right {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
outline: 1px solid;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
background: blue;
right: 300px;
border-right: 10px solid #fff;
}
```

what can i do? cheers

Comment: Both of those fiddles show the menu on the left …

Comment: Just remove the `width:100%` …

Comment: thanks cbroe, if you put it as an answer ill accept. cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `width:100%`.

The `left` and `right` coordinates of an `absolute` or `fixed` positioned element are enough to calculate the desired width.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the border:10px.. The white space is nothing but border...

```
    border-left: 10px solid #fff;
```

Either remove it or make it blue or red to remove the color distinguish.. :-)

Edited JSFiddle (I know it is not needed :P) : http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/ZQQ6s/23/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/xTPLG/

Check this link. It might help you.

```
#right {

height: auto;
outline: 1px solid;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
background: blue;
width:250px;
border-right: 10px solid #fff;
```

}